# CakePHP - Parameteried string

Tags: cakephp, parameter-passing, alert

I would like to show a dynamic message whenever user click on the delete link as followed:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->postLink(
                'Delete',
                array('action' => 'delete', $company['Company']['id']),
                array('confirm' => 'Are you sure to delete %s?',$company['Company']['name']));
```

The company name will be dynamic, but this code will print "Are you sure to delete %s?".

Do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It contains %s because there is no variable substitution. The name variable is not part of the confirm key (question code expanded):

```
<?php 
echo $this->Form->postLink(
    'Delete',
    array('action' => 'delete', $company['Company']['id']),
    array(
        'confirm' => 'Are you sure to delete %s?',
        0 => $company['Company']['name']
    )
);
```

### Use sprintf

Either use sprintf:

```
<?php 
echo $this->Form->postLink(
    'Delete',
    array('action' => 'delete', $company['Company']['id']),
    array('confirm' => sprintf('Are you sure to delete %s?',$company['Company']['name']))
);
```

### Use __

Or use the translation function (which [uses vsprintf](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/basics.php#L562)):

```
<?php 
echo $this->Form->postLink(
    'Delete',
    array('action' => 'delete', $company['Company']['id']),
    array('confirm' => __('Are you sure to delete %s?',$company['Company']['name']))
);
```